# How to fix "ERROR 1064 you have an error in your SQL syntax" in SQL coding

Tags: mysql, sql

The problem has asked me to write the SQL command to list the total sales by customer and by product, with subtotals by customer and a grand total for all product sales. However, the input I keep entering gives me back the results "ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax."

This is the code I have tried:

```
SELECT    CUS_CODE, P_CODE, SUM(SALE_UNTS*SALE_PRICE) AS TOTSALES
FROM      DWDAYSALESFACT NATURAL JOIN DWPRODUCT NATURAL JOIN DWVENDOR
GROUP BY  ROLLUP (CUS_CODE, P_CODE)
ORDER BY  CUS_CODE, P_CODE;
```

The results should show a CUS_CODE, P_CODE, and TOTSALES column.

Comment: Typically this error message includes a _"near..."_ part indicating the location of the bad syntax

Comment: Please post the rest of the error message. It gives more details, and it's right on the screen in front of you. Unfortunately, we can't see your screen from here, so you'll need to give us that information in your post. Use the [edit] link below the tags. Thanks.

Comment: Mate,
Would you please create a [fiddle](https://www.sqlfiddle.com) with a sample of your data and put the link in your question?

Comment: I'm not a MySQL expert, but I think you want `GROUP BY CUS_CODE, P_CODE WITH ROLLUP` instead of `GROUP BY ROLLUP( CUS_CODE, P_CODE )`.

Comment: My guess would be a problem with `ROLLUP`. I [cannot see a function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/func-op-summary-ref.html) with that name, just a [`WITH ROLLUP` modifier](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one the comments from @Dai your query should look like this.

```
SELECT    CUS_CODE, P_CODE, SUM(SALE_UNTS*SALE_PRICE) AS TOTSALES
FROM      DWDAYSALESFACT NATURAL JOIN DWPRODUCT NATURAL JOIN DWVENDOR
GROUP BY  CUS_CODE, P_CODE WITH ROLLUP 
ORDER BY  CUS_CODE, P_CODE;
```